# ASP .NET MVC 5 Checkbox loop for new created values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, html-helper

I have three entity classes:

```
namespace App.Data.Models
{
    public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }

    }
 
    public class Project
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
     public class EmployeeProject
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey]
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey]
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee  Employee{ get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    }
  
}
```

And one view model class

```
namespace App.Data.Models
{
public class EmployeeViewModel
    {
        public Employee Employee { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> Projects { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Right now I am able to add new employees and new projects. I am using localDB and Entity Framework. This is the link to my code https://github.com/IzaGorska/Project

What I want to do is to have checkbox for each project(need to have in mind that I don't have any hard coded projects - creating new project would mean extra checkbox) in EmployeeCreate view.
Also in EmployeeDetails view I want to display only checked projects. How can I do that?

I have db for employees and for project. Db for projects:

```
namespace App.Data.Services
{
    public interface IProjectData
    { 
        IEnumerable<Project> GetAll();
        Project Get(int id);
        void Add(Project project);
        void Update(Project project);   
    }
public class InMemoryProjectData : IProjectData
    {
        List<Project> projects;
        
        public void Add(Project project)
        {
            projects.Add(project);
            project.Id = projects.Max(e => e.Id) + 1;
        }

        public void Update(Project project)
        {
            var exist = Get(project.Id);
            if (exist != null)
            {
                exist.Name = project.Name;
                exist.Description = project.Description;

            }
        }
        public Project Get(int id)
        {
            return projects.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
        }

        public IEnumerable<Project> GetAll()
        {
            return projects.OrderBy(e => e.Name);
        }

    }
public class SQLProjectData : IProjectData
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext db;

        public SQLProjectData(AppDbContext db)
        {
            this.db = db;
        }

        public void Add(Project project)
        {
            db.Projects.Add(project);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        public Project Get(int id)
        {
            return db.Projects.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id); 
        }

        public IEnumerable<Project> GetAll()
        {
            return from p in db.Projects
                   orderby p.Name
                   select p;
        }

        public void Update(Project project)
        {
            var entry = db.Entry(project);
            entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller:

```
public partial class EmployeeController : Controller
{
private readonly AppDbContext _db;

  public EmployeeController(AppDbContext db)
    {
    _db = db;
}
 private List<SelectListItem> GetProjectListItems()
    {
        return _db.Projects.Select(p=> 
            new SelectListItem {
                         Text = p.Name, 
                          Value = p.Id.ToString()
                               }).ToList();
     }
        
  public IActionResult CreateEmployee()
  {
   var employeeViewModel=new EmployeeViewModel
   {
   Employee=new Employee(),
   Projects=GetProjectListItems()
   }
 return View(employeeViewModel);
 }
}
```

In the view you can use this code to create list of checkboxes:

```
@using App.Data.Models
@model EmployeeViewModel

.... @Model.Employee input controls
 
<ul>
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Projects.Count; i++)
        {
    <li>       
   <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.Projects[i].Selected"  />
   <label asp-for= "@Model.Projects[i].Selected"> @Model.Projects[i].Name</label>
   <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Projects[i].Value" />
   <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Project[i].Text" />                
    </li>
        }
</ul>
```

Comment: I have an error here -> DbContext.Projects -> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property and for p.Id -> Cannot implicitly convert int to string

Comment: I don't what you use. Where do you keep your data? Pls show. If you have a projectlist take just a projectlist, if you have a dbContext try to create new DbContext at first.

Comment: Do you use dependancy injection? Have you created any controllers?

Comment: One of the student  users  sent me this link https://github.com/ArminShoeibi/ImplicitManyToManyIdentityCore. You can  check it 
 for example. This is another one: https://github.com/AnthonyDaSilvaFe/OpenWebChallenge.API

Comment: Could you look at mine https://github.com/IzaGorska/Project and advise if so far it's good?

Comment: Did you try  to create checkboxes? I am sorry for the delay , but I am working every day. I am trying to find some time to help you but sometimes I can't . Can you tell me what is your chalenge now?

Comment: Thank you so much! I managed to create checkboxes as I wanted in Create view. I have used code you posted but I implemented GetProjectListItems method in interface for project. In contoller I am also using two db's - one for employees and one for projects, so I didn't use shared db. Now I am trying to fidure out how to display only checked projects in details and edit views.

Comment: Can you please advise me with the poject again? I am not sure how my post controller should look like. I want to push new data to EmployeeProject table - employeeid and projectid so I could display checked values in details view. I have created new post for this issue -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65957641/asp-net-mvc-5-how-can-i-push-selected-checkoxes-into-my-localdb